# Cannot login to mysql after setting incorrect mysql privileges/host

Tags: mysql, users, hosts, host

On CentOS 5.x I used webmin panel and I was in mysql settings, I was trying to allow "root" to login from my home ip in addition to localhost.
In the hosts list I had "any" or "localhost", I tried to make it "localhost,84.xx.xx.xx" thinking it will allow me to login from my local computer with mysql administrator program.

After I saved the entered data I cannot do much on mysql

Webmin says `DBI connect failed : Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'`

In SSH mysql says `ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'`

My guess is that mysql doesn't allow root to connect from any host anymore because I entered incorrect hosts.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling mysql but no change.
Is there a way to reset this? I have no database data, I can delete all if needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Log in at a terminal as root and stop the mysql daemon.

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

Then start up the mysql daemon and skip the grant tables which stores the passwords and other priviledge information

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

You should see mysqld start up successfully.
Now you should be able to connect to mysql without a password.

```
mysql --user=root mysql
```

and then update the relevant information:

```
update user set Password=PASSWORD('new-password') where user='root';
flush privileges;
exit;
```

and then restart the mysql daemon as you would normally do

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

Also take a look at the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-generic) to help you out if you get stuck

Comment: After `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` it gets stuck at `Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql`

Comment: It is not stuck it is running without problems. But I should have written : mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables & so it goes to the background and releases the prompt. Kill that process and start it again. 
Sorry for my mistake

Comment: After I did the `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` I was able to login in webmin again, I fixed the bad hosts format then saved and restarted mysql. It works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start mysql with `--skip-grant-tables` option. Have a look at [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html). After that, you should be able to connect to mysql database. You can then fix the error.